# Conditional expectation and limit

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

I'm wondering if $E^{F}[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} X_{n}] = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} E^{F}[X_{n}]$ with for exemple $X_{n}$ non negative mesurable function.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely true. You can verify it from definition of conditional expectations using Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Oh yes now I see, thank you.
So $A \mapsto E[1_{A} | F]$ is a probability ! And now we can even wonder if it is a density or the law of a mesurable function.